# Problem returning a value in function c++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, return

I am just staritng to learn c++ and i ran into a problem where i am not able to return a value in a function. Here is the function.

```
static int total()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        static int ongoing_sum = 0;
        static int total = ongoing_sum + assets[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Now, returning the `total_sum` from inside the `for` loop is not what i want and if i move it outside of the for loop, it is already deleted from the memory(according to my understanding). How would i return this `total_sum` value? Also, i dont want to use includes like iterator in my code. Thanks

Edit: Forgot to mention `assets` is an array `int assets[50];`.

Comment: *"if i move it outside of the for loop, it is already deleted from the memory"* It's not completely clear to me what you mean by this, but it's probably incorrect.

Comment: where is `total_sum` coming from?

Comment: If you are talking about `total`, it is a POD. You can return it fine.

Comment: I meant its life time is over and because the for loop dosen't exist anymore , the variable "total" dosent either.

Comment: @hippozhipos Its lifetime is not over. The lifetime of static object ends after `main` has returned. The problem is that the variable is declared in another scope.

Comment: @eerorika Ah right thanks for clearing that, i must have misunderstood what that youtuber told me

Comment: @hippozhipos you have no idea how easy that is to do. Given [Sturgeon's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) it is also possible that the youtuber has no damn clue what they are saying and trying to follow the tutorial is actively making you stupider. That's the problem with online tutorials: If you understand the material well enough to know whether the tutorial is good or not you probably don't need the tutorial.

Comment: @user4581301 It's also possible that hippozhipos took correct advice and generalised it to a case where it does not apply.

Comment: Agreed. There's no way to know. You put down your money, roll the dice, and hope you've tilted probability in your favour enough for a good outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it outside the loop:

```
int total()
{
    int total_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        total_sum += assets[i];
    }

    return total_sum;
}
```

Here I assume you didn't mean to make it `static` as it doesn't make much sense. If it should be static, you can still make it static.

Comment: If it wasent static, wouldnt the value reset to 0 everytime it loops?

Comment: @hippozhipos, no. It resets to zero every time the function is called. `static`, in this case, retains values between function calls. Local variables would retain their value throughout the iterations of the loop.

Comment: @hippozhipos Do you mean everytime it loops or everytime the function called?

Comment: @hippo `static` variables in functions are declared only once, the first time they are encountered during the program's lifetime. If you make it `static` anywhere, then every time you call `total`, it will use whatever the most recent value of `total_sum` was the last time you called the function.

Answer (score 0):

`int total(int assets[])`
`{`
    `int total_sum = 0;`
`for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)`
    `{`
       `total_sum +=assets[i];` 
    `}`

```
`return total_sum; }`
```

Comment: Always remember that array can only be passed as reference in an argument of a function in only the following 3 ways